# Application_Error no longer triggers when published to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

OK I have the following code in my Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception objError = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        Response.Redirect(
            String.Format(
            "/Error/{0}/{1}",
            ((HttpException)objError).GetHttpCode(),
            Request.RawUrl));
}
```

To provide neat and tidy error urls like "/Error/404/TheNameOfTheRequestedPage". This works fine from VS 2008, but once published to my local machine, I get the default error page:

> **Error Summary**
>
> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has
>   been removed, had its name changed, or
>   is temporarily unavailable

Anyone know how to do this? I've chosen not to use system.web/customErrors because I don't have access to Server.GetLastError() from there (or at least it's never worked for me) and I want to get the http code.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely related to you triggering an IIS Http Error which is defined in the web.config under the nodes

```
<system.webServer>    
    <httpErrors>
    </httpErrors>    
<system.webServer>
```

If the issue is you're returning an a response code for 404 and getting the IIS 404 page the issue is you need to do

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Before you let the response finish otherwise IIS will intercept the error.

This is completely beyond unintuitive especially if you set the status code yourself. I tried to figure a way to file a bug on Microsoft Connect that manually setting a http error code does not automatically set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` but could not seem to figure out any relevant product to submit it to.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and a call to `Server.ClearError()` before the redirect did solve the problem.

In your case I would write

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs 
        Exception objError = Server.GetLastError(); 
        if(objError is HttpException){
          //Need to clear the error, otherwise the buil-in redirect would occure
          Server.ClearError(); 
          Response.Redirect( 
              String.Format( 
              "/Error/{0}/{1}", 
              ((HttpException)objError).GetHttpCode(), 
              Request.RawUrl)); 
        }
}
```

Notice that Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException() returns the **base** exception, which isn't always the HttpException, the one you are looking for is just GetLastError().